# Is my ER Diagram correct?

Tags: sql, erd

So I have this database called "Lyric", and I am supposed to take 4 tables and make an ER diagram on these tables. Here, I picked "Artists", "Title", "Genre" and "Studios".
One note: this is my very first time doing this, and this is not even in the objectives of the class. We  are merely introduced to the concept of ER diagrams in this introductory class.

Here is the "Lyric" database: [image]

and here is my ER diagram on those 4 tables I mentioned above:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1 Artist has N Titles, so it should be 1 by Artists and N by Titles. The relation is the same type as Studio - Title.
I would try to avoid `has` as a description of a relation. Title is e.g. `performed by` Artist.